# networkengineering. or askubuntu

Tags: discussion, scope

if you have a question that is related to networking for example dhcp or ftp servives and your application is on the ubuntu . In which stack you should or better to ask networkengineering or askubuntu?

Comment: Depends on the question. You haven't really given us much to go on.

Comment: Can you say that in general I can link to one question if you want but need a red line I think not so difficult to depict that line

Comment: No, I can't really say for general without a more specific example. If you're running Ubuntu though the question *should* be on-topic here. I don't know anything about network engineering though.

Comment: this link is an easy question but I think this link is good. like to read your opinion and suggestion : http://askubuntu.com/questions/469241/domain-name-in-dhcp

Comment: Brief aside... I think your example question would have gotten more upvotes if it had been worded/formatted more clearly.  I tried to help with that ;)

Comment: thank you very much :-)

Comment: networkengineering is still in beta and mostly focuses on Enterprise network solutions(i.e. Cisco and Juniper) and the configuration of said routers, switches, firewalls, etc. IMHO, we shouldn't be re-directing folks to a beta site when most of the Ubunutu specific question can be addressed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer:

Yes, I like it on AskUbuntu.

#### TLDR answer:

If it deals with configuring a network service on an Ubuntu machine, it could easily be asked in either place.

That said, I like the idea of putting the question on AskUbuntu.  Why is that the case?

It's simple.

We used to get questions like that much more often.  It's refreshing to get a good question that might be helpful to Ubuntu users that are doing configuration

*as opposed to*

troubleshooting or incorrectly reporting bugs via AskUbuntu without first searching launchpad.